# FASTAPI How to merge object properties into one object

Tags: python, postgresql, object, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm creating social media app with FASTAPI framework. I'm joining likes using sqlalchemy.orm into post table. The data I get is correct but I want everything to be under post object rather then having post/likes object

Here are the models

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
   id: int
   email: EmailStr

class Config:
    orm_mode = True

class PostBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
class BasePostResponse(PostBase):
    id: int
    created_at: datetime
    user: UserBase

class Config:
    orm_mode = True

class PostResponse(BaseModel):
    SocialPost: BasePostResponse = Field(alias="data")
    likes: int

class Config:
    orm_mode = True
    allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

Here is how I join and get all the posts

```
    @router.get("/all", response_model= List[socialMedia.PostResponse])
def get_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db), per_page: int = 50, page: int = 1, search: Optional[str] = ""):
    posts = db.query(models.SocialPost, func.count(models.SocialLikes.post_id).label('likes')).join(models.SocialLikes, models.SocialLikes.post_id == models.SocialPost.id, isouter= True).group_by(models.SocialPost.id).filter(models.SocialPost.title.contains(search)).limit(per_page).offset(per_page * (page - 1)).all()

    return posts
```

The response I get

```
[
        {
        "data": {
            "title": "First post",
            "description": "First Desc",
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-09-19T21:47:45.660685+02:00",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "admin@test.com"
            }
        },
        "likes": 0
    },
...
]
```

And I would like to just get

```
[
  {
     "title": "First post",
     "description": "First Desc",
     "id": 2,
     "created_at": "2022-09-19T21:47:45.660685+02:00",
     "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "admin@test.com"
     },
     "likes": 0
    },
...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.

In the models, under post table I used likes =column_property(select([func.count ...

So, in the schemas I just added the likes property to original PostResponse and it returns the response I desired

Leaving this in case anyone else struggles :)

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer, if you wish to do so.